# Bean Validation - constructor/factory parameter

Tags: java, jackson, bean-validation, jersey-2.0, hibernate-validator

I have a dto object which keeps an IP Range using first and last fields. Simple CRUD operations are made with this class using dropwizard (jersey-jackson-hibernate validator)

```
public class IpRangeDto {

  @JsonCreator
  public static IpRangeDto fromCidr(@JsonProperty("cidr") String cidr) {
      //Resolve CIDR and assign first and last fields
  }

  @NotNull
  @IpAddress  // My custom validator
  private String first;

  @NotNull
  @IpAddress
  private String last;
}
```

For the sake of user-friendliness I had decided to add an alternative way to create this object, which is by using CIDR. So the client could send either `first` and `last` fields in JSON or only the `cidr` field. So the way to do it is as above, using @JsonCreator. And it works just fine.

```
"ipRange":{
  "first": "15.0.0.1",
  "last": "15.0.0.255",
}

"ipRange":{
  "cidr": "15.0.0.0/24"
}
```

I want to validate this CIDR value that it's the right format so I can return 422 with proper error message. If I throw exception in the constructor/factory method then jersey-jackson returns 400 directly (even if I throw `ConstraintViolationException`, it's encapsulated by `JsonProcessingException`).

I could simply ignore the exceptions, and leave the fields empty which will return 422 because of `@NotNull` constraints but then the error message will not be as clear as it should be.

I tried adding my `@Cidr` validator next to the `@JsonProperty` parameter but that doesn't seem to be effective. My understanding is that validation occurs after Jackson is finished with creating Dtos, so with my `@JsonCreator` approach there might not be any solution to this problem. So I'm open to refactoring suggestions as well.

Answer (score 1):

I am not an expert on the exact integration of Bean Validation into jackson, but I think it is just doing actual property validation. This means as you already pointed out, the entities are created first and then the properties are validated.

Bean Validation (as of version 1.1) also offers so called method validation, in which case you could place your `Cidr` constraint onto the string parameter of the method, but as said, I don't think that there is an integration in jackson for that.

And one more thing ;-) - static methods and properties are generally excluded from validation in Bean Validation (see also http://beanvalidation.org/1.1/spec/#d0e2815).

Regarding a workaround, one thing comes to mind (even though it feels a bit complicated). Write a custom class level `IpRange` constraint. In a class constraint you would get passed a `IpRangeDto` instance and it is up to you to validate the whole object and select the right error message for any violations. Provided you would add a cidr property to the dto which gets set when `fromCidr` is called, you would have then all information you need for the validation and selection of a proper error message.